# Compilation with /MTd fails with: error C3193 '^': requires '/clr' or '/ZW' command line option

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli

Project compiles successfuly using `Multi-threaded (/MT)` option. However when switched to `Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)` build fails getting: `Error C3193 '^': requires '/clr' or '/ZW' command line option`

If there is no possibility of using `/clr` because of `/MTd` how to add `/ZW` option?

**SOLUTIONS TRIED**

- In General tab enable `No Common Language Runtime Support` option. Build still fails with the same error message.

Comment: If you are getting this error then it means that your application *requires* Common Language Runtime Support or Component Extensions support. Also `/clr` and `/ZW` are not alternatives, because they are used to compile code written in *different* languages.

Comment: You should figure out which language are you using: C++, C++/CLI or C++/Cx and then act accordingly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Project built successfuly with `Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)` option by disabling `Conformance Mode`.